# Not receiving dateRange objects via DSCC

Tags: looker-studio, data-studio-custom-visuals

I would like to use the dateRanges to limit the axis of my visual, but I am not receiving it.

According to the documentation, dscc subscribed data should have the following fields:

`{ fields: object(fieldsByConfigId), style: object(styleById), interactions: object(interactionsById), theme: object(themeStyle), tables: object(tablesById), dateRanges: object(dateRangesById) }`

When I check the object my custom visual is receiving, I do not get the dateRanges object. Anyone else having the same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pedro!

I just faced the same problem. This is absolutely crazy, but yes, by default we can't access "data ranges".

But the good news is that I found how to fix it!

We need to modify the code, that Google gives us with file `dscc.min.js` in their [doc](https://developers.google.com/looker-studio/visualization/library)

I pushed the updated code and some explanations in my public repo [here](https://github.com/aryzhkin/google-looker-studio-custom-visualization-dateranges).

Or you can find this code:

```js
...interactions: s(e)...`
```

and paste after it this:

```js
...interactions: s(e), customDataRanges: Boolean(e.dataResponse.dateRanges) ? e.dataResponse.dateRanges : null
```

**Pay attention**, that you should do it twice:

1. For objectTransform
2. For tableTransform
   Or just take the file from my [repo](https://github.com/aryzhkin/google-looker-studio-custom-visualization-dateranges).

**Pay attention 2**, that you can access ranges with `customDataRanges` (not `dataRanges`), like this:

```js
function drawViz(data) {
  console.log(data.customDataRanges);
}
dscc.subscribeToData(drawViz, { transform: dscc.tableTransform });
```

Hope my answer will help someone.

UPD:
"Data Controls do not currently work with Community Visualizations", from here: https://developers.google.com/looker-studio/visualization/issues